# Dissolving/Unifying Ill Behaved/Irregular Polygons in R

Tags: raster, polygon, r, sp, maptools

I'm working on a project involving bringing together multiple subjects circling difficult to find parts of an image. The output from users is pretty awesome.

[image: Four classifications]

Cool, right?

However, what I want is to get the area of the image that has 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. users selecting it. And I'm using R for the analysis with the sp, raster, and maptools packages (with a little rgeos throw in when need be). Essentially, my workflow is to 
1) create a single polygon from each user's input (I actually have the track of each individual selection per user, but it seemed easier to combine them into a single SpatialPolygon per user)
2) merge them all together into a single SpatialPolygonsDataFrame Object
3) Rasterize the object using the count function
4) Assess area of the raster with n number of users selecting it

[Here's the output SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to play with](https://github.com/jebyrnes/floatingForests/blob/master/data/oneImage2_spdf.Rdata?raw=true)

This works great, but is slooow due to the rasterization. I feel like I should be able to do something with the SpatialPolygons object. And I've tried a few things with union, gIntersects, gUnion, and intersect. However, I keep getting errors such as the following

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, "rgeos_difference") : 
TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point
```

Fair enough. Often a given users SpatialPolygons are invalid when I test them using gIsValid. Looking at, say, just the first two, this becomes obvious that there are many overlapping points.

[image: Polygons one and two]

You can see the intersecting points pretty clearly. Furthermore, in poly2 (the blue) there appears to be some self-intersection, causing gIsValid to return false.

I've also tried unionSpatialPolygons (with avoidRGEOS=T) which creates a unified object

  `unionSpatialPolygons(polysData[1:2,], 
  IDs=names(polysData[1:2,]@polygons))`

But the borders still overlap like in the above image, rather than being one smooth polygon outer border - i.e., the polygons are not dissolved together. Then using any further functions on this new SpatialPolygons object, I have the same problems.

So, is there a way to use polygons instead of going to rasters? It sure would make my life faster, which would be excellent.  I feel like this must be a common problem with a wheel invented that I have yet to find. Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting question ... are you open to other FOSS tools like GRASS or PostGIS?

Comment: As long as it's scriptable (as I have a huge amount of datasets just like this one), then yes!

Comment: If the answer I gave below doesn't help, can find a GRASS solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like cleaning the geometry up will get you on the road to your non-raster solution ... herewith something of a kludge which does help with fixing bad geometry:

```
# Load the library and problematic data
library(rgeos)
load("oneImage2_spdf.Rdata")

>gIsValid(polysData, reason = T)
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, "rgeos_union") : 
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -119.84228271000001 34.349193950783807 at -119.84228271000001 34.349193950783807
```

That's the offending data; perhaps only a single point, but doing a buffer by 0 width should fix it.

```
# Let's buffer by 0:
polysData <- gBuffer(polysData, width=0, byid = T)
```

gBuffer doesn't like this - there's an unprojected CRS attached to it!

```
Warning message:
In gBuffer(polysData, width = 0, byid = T) :
  Spatial object is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates
```

Time to trick rgeos:

```
# Set to a projected CRS - could be anything
polysCRS <- polysData@proj4string
polysData@proj4string <- CRS("+init=epsg:32737")

# Now buffer it but preserve individual objects
polysData <- gBuffer(polysData, width = 0, byid = T)

# Reset the original CRS
polysData@proj4string <- polysCRS
```

Check if geometry's valid:

```
>gIsValid(polysData, reason = T)
"Valid Geometry"
```

Comment: @jebyrnes, did this work for you?

Comment: Huh. It did!  Thanks! Now I need to figure out a bit more about how to tell how many of the polygons overlapped from gUnionCascaded - that heatmap, if you will, but the gBuffer made the geometry valid!

Comment: Just a word of caution, The `gBuffer` function 'fixes' the problem by removing the self-intersecting polygons. To visualize what I mean before running `gBuffer`, create a copy of polysData: `polysData_original <- polysData`

then use gBuffer as above and then plot both sets of polygons:

`for(i in seq_along(polysData)){
plot(polysData_original[i,],col='red');
plot(polysData[i,],col='green',add=T);
title(i);
}`

Answer (score 4):

Without your original data, I can't be sure this will work, but I thought it might help you out. I didn't bring it all the way there, this solution still likely needs some level of automation, but might give you a general way forward

First, I create some spatial polygons

```
polypoints1 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2),ncol=2)
polypoints2 <- matrix(c(1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,1,3),ncol=2)
polypoints3 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2)+1.1,ncol=2)
polypoints4 <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2)+0.5,ncol=2)

p1 <- Polygon(polypoints1)
ps1 <- Polygons(list(p1),1)
sps1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps1))

p2 <- Polygon(polypoints2)
ps2 <- Polygons(list(p2),2)
sps2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps2))

p3 <- Polygon(polypoints3)
ps3 <- Polygons(list(p3),3)
sps3 <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps3))

p4 <- Polygon(polypoints4)
ps4 <- Polygons(list(p4),4)
sps4 <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps4))
```

I plotted them just to see

```
plot(sps2,col='green')
plot(sps1,add=T,col='blue')
plot(sps3,add=T,col='yellow')
plot(sps4,add=T,col='purple')
```

I merged them into an spdf

```
data=data.frame(c(x=rep(1,4)),row.names=c(1:4))
sps <- SpatialPolygons(list(ps1,ps2,ps3,ps4))
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sps,data)
```

You can identify which polygon overlaps which like so:

```
gIntersects(spdf,spdf,byid =T)
```

From the above command you could create some kind of loops to do the overlapping combinations below (I'm just ignoring sps4 for brevity at this point)

```
poly2a <- gIntersection(spdf[2,],spdf[1,],drop_lower_td=T)
poly2a <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly2a,data.frame(c(x=1),row.names=c(1)))
plot(poly2a,add=T,col='red')
```

This time we need to change the ID since we're going to rbind these later

```
poly2b <- gIntersection(spdf[2,],spdf[3,],drop_lower_td=T)
poly2b <- spChFIDs(poly2b,"2")
poly2b <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly2b,data.frame(c(x=1),row.names=c(2)))
plot(poly2b,add=T,col='red')
```

Merge the overlapping polygons into another spdf

```
spdf_overlaps <- rbind(poly2a,poly2b)
poly2 <- unionSpatialPolygons(spdf_overlaps,rep(1,2))
plot(poly2,add=T,col='blue')
```

Now we have poly2 which is where we have 2 layers overlapping (except combinations with sps4) then to figure out 3 layers, we just have to check out where poly2 and spdf overlap (if you make a more automated version of this, you'll need to make sure that 'poly2' does not include sps4 as in this example)

```
gIntersects(poly2,spdf[4,],byid =T)

poly3 <- gIntersection(poly2,spdf[4,],drop_lower_td=T)
plot(poly3,add=T,col="red")
```

Check it out

```
gIsValid(poly2)
gIsValid(poly3)
```

**Alternatively**, you could always do a pseudo rasterization, much easier, but you loose some detail depending on your cell size:

First make the grid:

```
bb <- bbox(spdf)
cs <- c(0.1,0.1)  # cell size
cc <- bb[, 1] + (cs/2)  # cell offset
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)  # number of cells per direction
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=cc, cellsize=cs, cells.dim=cd)


sp_grd <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd,
                           data=data.frame(id=1:prod(cd)))
```

Then, make grid into a polygon which used for overlap

```
library(Grid2Polygons)
grid <- Grid2Polygons(sp_grd)
plot(grid)
```

Then count the number of polygons that overlap each grid cell

```
count <- apply(gContains(spdf,grid,byid=T),1,sum)
```

Finally, plot it!

```
plot(grid)
for(i in 1:length(grid)){
    plot(grid[i,],col=rev(heat.colors(3))[count[i]],add=T)
}
```

Comment: FYI - https://github.com/jebyrnes/floatingForests/blob/master/data/oneImage2_spdf.Rdata?raw=true is the spdf from the above example.

Comment: The gIntersects method still fails with the above data. I like the pseudo-rasterization idea. Indeed, the original polygons can be made on the scale of the image - so, 1 pixel = 1 point, and then the ultimate overlapping polygon can be projected for area calculation. This would take a wee bit of doing with respect to my workflow, but, if it's the only solution...

Comment: Ahhh, I see, the original data has self intersecting polygons, I think the only purely R solution will be to use the pseudo-rasterized method. As far as I know, R can't handle cleaning those up. But they could be cleaned up in GRASS, or PostGIS, or begrudgingly in ArcGIS 
Check out: 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141179/fix-self-intersecting-polygons-manually

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-January/017273.html

Comment: I just found out R and GRASS can interact! http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics

If you figure out how to fix your polygons in GRASS, you should be able to automate it in R

Answer (score 2):

Applying a buffer with width=0 can be risky for some polygons, e.g. cases of bowtie polygons, altering a lot source geometries. You can try to use the [cleangeo](https://github.com/eblondel/cleangeo/wiki) package which aims to fix spatial objects. You can install it from Github or from CRAN. You can use this simple code to correct your spatial object:

```
library(cleangeo)
polysData.clean <- clgeo_Clean(polysData)

#check geometry validity of output
gIsValid(polysData.clean)
```